# how scikit learn figure out logistic regression for classification or regression

Tags: python, python-2.7, machine-learning, scikit-learn, logistic-regression

I think logistic regression could be used for both regression (get number between 0 and 1, e.g. using logistic regression to predict a probability between 0 and 1) and classification. The question is, it seems after we provide the training data and target, logistic regression could automatically figure out if we are doing a regression or doing a classification?

For example, in below example code, logistic regression figured out we just need output to be one of the 3 class `0, 1, 2`, other than any number between `0` and `2`? Just curious how logistic regression automatically figured out whether it is doing a regression (output is a continuous range) or classification (output is discrete) problem?

http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/linear_model/plot_iris_logistic.html

```
print(__doc__)


# Code source: Gaël Varoquaux
# Modified for documentation by Jaques Grobler
# License: BSD 3 clause

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from sklearn import linear_model, datasets

# import some data to play with
iris = datasets.load_iris()
X = iris.data[:, :2]  # we only take the first two features.
Y = iris.target

h = .02  # step size in the mesh

logreg = linear_model.LogisticRegression(C=1e5)

# we create an instance of Neighbours Classifier and fit the data.
logreg.fit(X, Y)

# Plot the decision boundary. For that, we will assign a color to each
# point in the mesh [x_min, m_max]x[y_min, y_max].
x_min, x_max = X[:, 0].min() - .5, X[:, 0].max() + .5
y_min, y_max = X[:, 1].min() - .5, X[:, 1].max() + .5
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.arange(x_min, x_max, h), np.arange(y_min, y_max, h))
Z = logreg.predict(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])

# Put the result into a color plot
Z = Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.figure(1, figsize=(4, 3))
plt.pcolormesh(xx, yy, Z, cmap=plt.cm.Paired)

# Plot also the training points
plt.scatter(X[:, 0], X[:, 1], c=Y, edgecolors='k', cmap=plt.cm.Paired)
plt.xlabel('Sepal length')
plt.ylabel('Sepal width')

plt.xlim(xx.min(), xx.max())
plt.ylim(yy.min(), yy.max())
plt.xticks(())
plt.yticks(())

plt.show()
```

Comment: `I think logistic regression could be used for both regression [...] and classification` - in principle yes, but if people say logistic regression, they always refer to the classification algorithm (yes, this is weird). The regression case is a special case of `generalized linear models` with a logit link funktion.

Comment: @cel, nice catch and vote up. If I want logistic regression to output value between 0 and 1, how should I do? Suppose 0 means people not purchased something, 1 means people purchase something, I want to predict the probability of purchase using logistic regression. The target has only value 0 and 1 in my case, but I want to predict a float number between 0 and 1 for probability.

Comment: @LinMa use logreg.predict_proba() http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.predict_proba

Comment: Thanks @joc, vote up. I think sigmoid function output continuous value between 0 and 1, but logistic regression in scikit learn by default output either 0 or 1 for a classification problem. Just curious how scikit learn automatically figure out and normalize output to either 0 or 1, is there a threshold scikit learn logistic regression utilizing underlying? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Logistic regression often uses a cross-entropy cost function, which models loss according to a binary error. Also, the output of logistic regression usually follows a sigmoid at the decision boundary, meaning that while the decision boundary may be linear, the output (often viewed as a probability of the point representing one of two classes on either side of the boundary) transitions in non-linear fashion. This would make your regression model from 0 to 1 a very particular, non-linear function. That might be desirable in certain circumstances, but is probably not generally desirable.

You can think of logistic regression as providing an amplitude that represents probability of being in a class, or not. If you consider a binary classifier with two independent variables, you can picture a surface where the decision boundary is the topological line where probability is 0.5. Where the classifier is certain the of the class, the surface is either on the plateau (probability = 1) or in the low lying region (probability = 0). The transition from low probability regions to high follows a sigmoid function, usually.

You might look at Andrew Ng's Coursera course, which has a set of classes on logistic regression. [This](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5oZM1Izn3c&list=PLZ9qNFMHZ-A4rycgrgOYma6zxF4BZGGPW&index=33) is the first of the classes. I have a github repo that is the R version of that class's output, [here](https://github.com/johnyetter/R-CourseraML/tree/master/Rmlclass-ex2), which you might find helpful in understanding logistic regression better.

Comment: Hi John, thanks for the reply. I understand how logistic regression works. My question is more on scikit learn part, you can refer to my post example code, my question is why the prediction result is discrete 0, 1 or 2, other than continuous sigmoid function output? Just wondering how scikit learn automatically figure out I need a classification output (discrete) other than continuous output.

Comment: BTW, John, vote up for your patient answer. For your reply, there is one thing I do not quite clear. I am always use EM (max likelihood) to estimate parameter `w`, how it is related to cross entropy here?

Comment: When you say parameter w, do you mean the class_weight? I am not seeing a w parameter in the scikit-learn docs. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: Hi John, apologize for the confusion and vote up for your reply. When I say parameter, I mean the coefficient to learn in logistic regression. `y = (1+exp(w*x)) ^ (-1)`, I mean `w` in for the coefficient. If you could comment on my question how scikit learn figure out I need to classification (output is discrete) other than regression (output is continuous), it will be great. As you can see, after learn coefficient `w`, `y(hat)` is between 0 and 1, so I think logistic regression in scikit learn must have some threshold as well to normalize output to either 0 or 1.

Comment: Ah, yes. Generally, you use a threshold to transform the output of logistic regression, which is often taken as a probability between 0 and 1, into a prediction (either 0 or 1). So, this is definitely what is happening. I am not certain if Scikit learn allows you to set the threshold. With regard to cross entropy and finding an optimal set of coefficients, the loss function is convex, and scikit learn offers a few different convex optimization methods for solving the optimization problem.

Comment: Thanks John for the reply and vote up, do you mean internally logistic regression in scikit learn actually produce value between `0` and `1`, but it convert to either `0` and `1` for a classification problem?

Comment: In the multiclass case, the logistic regression class uses the one-versus-rest scheme. Looking at the scikit learn code, this sets a threshold at 0.5 and weighs the probability predictions against that threshold to provide predictions.

Comment: Thanks John for the advice. Vote up for your reply. Sorry I have not made myself understood, my question is only in a two class scenario, when we call logistic regression to fit a model and try to predict some results. How could logistic regression know if output should be either `0` or `1` (a classification problem), or the output should be some continuous value between `[0,1]`?